# Yii2 - onsubmit event is fired twice

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to make submit event properly (onsubmit is set inline), but it will be fired twice, which is not desired behavior.

My **ActiveForm** code:

```
<?php

use app\models\Countries;
use app\models\States;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;

$form = ActiveForm::begin(
    [
        'action'  => 'user-default-shipping/create',
        'options' => [
            'onsubmit' => 'Address.createDefault(event, this)'
        ]

    ]
);

if ($model->id)
    echo Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'id');

echo $form->field($model, 'city')->textInput();

echo $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput();

echo $form->field($model, 'zip')->input('text');

echo $form->field($model, 'country_id')
    ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Countries::find()->all(), 'country_id', 'country_name'),
        ['role' => 'countries']
    )->hint('Choose your country.');

echo $form->field($model, 'state_id')
    ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(States::find()->all(), 'state_id', 'state_name'),
        [
            'role' => 'states'
        ]
    )->hint('Choose your state.');

?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green">Submit</button>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

JS code:

```
const Address = {

    createDefault(event, form) {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(form);

    }

}
```

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: ummm... you are trying to create your custom event which will trigger on the submission of the form? why not using the default events provided by `ActiveForm` js ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - I am a bit rusty with yii2, what is the default event for ajax submition?

Comment: added an answer for you see if it helps you out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Default events provided by the [**`ActiveForm Js Library`**](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/)

### Using events

```
$('#contact-form').on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {
    if (!confirm("Everything is correct. Submit?")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Available events are:

- beforeValidate.
- afterValidate.
- beforeValidateAttribute.
- afterValidateAttribute.
- beforeSubmit.
- ajaxBeforeSend.
- ajaxComplete.

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks mate :)